# What is the meaning of "Docile pitch behavior" in the context of Pugachev's Cobra?

Tags: aerodynamics, military, aerobatics, maneuver, theory

In another answer on SE Aviation it is mentioned that the ability to perform  Pugachev's Cobra  in a non-thrust-vectored aircraft needs *"docile pitch behavior of the airframe up to approx. 110° angle of attack"*

[image]

[Can an F-16 perform Pugachev's Cobra?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/can-an-f-16-perform-pugachevs-cobra)

What does "docile pitch behavior" mean in this context? Does it mean that when the control surfaces are returned to neutral the aircraft has a natural pitch down moment that returns it to its horizontal position?

If so, does the pilot actually have control over how long he can hold the vertical position in Pugachev's Cobra? What control surface enables him to exercise this authority in the post-stall regime when I'd have assumed the 
control surfaces lack such authority?

Or is the holding time of the vertical attitude in Pugachev's Cobra beyond the pilot's control and only related to some sort of "natural period" of this maneuver in that aircraft linked to how long it takes the restoring moment to return the aircraft to its nose down attitude?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Docile" means no big pitching moments over the angle of attack range. Since the control power with fully stalled control surfaces is rather small, the airframe must not create strong pitching moments, but keep a small pitch-down moment so the airplane returns eventually to normal angles of attack which allow regular flight.

The maneuver is dynamic, so the pilot needs to build up a specific pitch rate. Inertia will keep the aircraft pitching up, and the small pitch-down moment (and aerodynamic damping) will reduce the pitch rate so that the pitch-up stops when the nose is pointing straight up. What follows is the consequence of the small pitch-down moment: The aircraft slowly returns to controlled flight, and once control authority is re-established, the pilot stops the pitching motion.

By selecting the initial pitch rate, the pilot can control the maximum angle of attack, but once he leaves the flight regime of attached flow, he has to wait until inertia and aerodynamics do their part.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand it better. So the max cobra duration is essentially proportional to whatever max initial pitch rate the pilot can achieve to enter the manouever? i.e. The greater the initial pitch rate the longer it takes the damping and restoring pitch-down moment to return the aircraft to controlled flight?

Comment: And to enter the maneuver is it correct to say that the pilot gets a lot of initial forward velocity and stable forward trajectory and pulls back on the stick rather fast and holds it there till pitch authority is lost post-stall? And then just waits it out till the plane completes the cobra and returns to controlled flight in the forward direction? Or is there more to it?

Comment: @curious_cat: Yes. There might be more with specific elevator angles post-stall, but in essence that is it.

Comment: Does the elevator retain authority post-stall?

Comment: Also, how come there isn't a lot of altitude loss during the Cobra? Aren't we converting a streamlined, low drag attitude into essentially a large air brake + spoiler?

Comment: @curious_cat Your high drag results in a speed loss primarily.

Comment: @curious_cat Don't forget the thrust vector. At the top of the maneuver you're getting esdentially no lift. The engines are maintaining altitude. And I think the loss of airspeed is the whole purpose of the maneuver (besides looking cool). Turns a pursuer into the pursuee

Comment: @curious_cat: Elevator post-stall authority is very small. It will produce a drag force that is proportional to its projected area in streamwise direction. Say it is flying at 80° AoA. Rotating the fully-flying tail by -20° to 60° will change the projected area by (sin80°-sin60°)/sin80° = 12%. 12% less drag at the tail will add a small pitch-up increment.

Comment: @TomMcW Do the engines have enough thrust to maintain altitude directly against gravity? e.g.  On a Sukhoi Su-30 the powerplant is 2 × AL-31FL offering max dry thrust of 75 kN each. If I'm crunching my numbers right this will only support 15 tons. But the Empty weight of the Sukhoi is 18 tons and with 50% fuel somewhere around 25 tons. What gives? Or will afterburners be used typically during a Pugachev's Cobra?

Comment: @curious_cat After watching videos of several ac performing the cobra (like [this one](https://youtu.be/daOPK07baBw) from YouTube) it appears they gain some upward momentum with the first part of the pitch-up. They don't appear to lose any at all during. The momentum of the climb will help. Then the power of the engines holds them there. . .

Comment: . . . I don't know how to tell if the afterburners are engaged or not but that would prob be a good guess. A few of them exhibit a trail when they are doing the cobra but I can't say if it's exhaust or vapor. I'm thinking afterburners may create a smoke trail because they might not have quite enough oxygen for complete combustion and could produce visible smoke. But that's just conjecture. Peter could prob confirm if that is true or not

Comment: @TomMcW You are right. Even the set of images illustrating the maneuver I borrowed from Wikipedia shows a slight altitude increase and then decrease. So that must be the contribution from the initial upwards momentum and the pitch up contribution. So I guess it isn't a constant altitude manouver in a strict sense. Altitude is first gained and then lost.