# How does an airplane do a Kulbit manoeuvre?

Tags: aerobatics, maneuver

Some time ago, I came across a GIF of a Russian military airplane doing a Kulbit manoeuvre (Probably for showoff). How, in terms of control surface movement, does an airplane to the Kulbit?

[image]
<sup>Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/interestingasfuck/comments/28w8yv/the_kulbit_maneuver_xpost_from_raviationgifs/)</sup>

Comment: Thrust vectoring probably had a significant role to play.

Comment: @mins Readward salto

Comment: @mins It looks like the Kulbit so I will say that it is.

Comment: after seeing the video, I agree with Ron, without TV is not doable.

Comment: Upon seeing that clip, I can't help but recall this famous line: *"Son, your ego is writing checks your body can't cash."*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Kulbit maneuver is a variation on the [Cobra maneuver](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24292/pugachevs-cobra-aerodynamics-meaning-of-docile-pitch-behavior) (Pugachev's Cobra) with a higher pitch rate and continuous positive pitch rate throughout the maneuver. It requires two things:

- A docile pitch behavior of the airframe over the full angle of attack range of 360°. Docile means that the pitch moments stay low and do not change abruptly with the angle of attack.
- Thrust vectoring nozzles to keep the pitch rate up.

An electronic flight system is helpful to make execution easier, but is not strictly required. Also helpful is an engine-intake-combination which does not stall the compressor if the outer flow is reversed briefly. As you can see, the control surfaces only play a minor role - they are only important initially to start the pitch-up motion. This is done by negative elevator and/or positive canard deflection.